# Maven compilation fails when class becomes inner class (although Eclipse is good)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, compiler-errors, inner-classes

I have a class:

```
public class Stuff implements OtherStuff<BigInteger>
```

Which builds perfectly using Eclipse and Maven.  However, I really want this class to be an inner class, but when I do:

```
public class ParentStuff {
.
.
.
    public static class Stuff implements OtherStuff<BigInteger>
```

Eclipse builds perfectly but now Maven tells me OtherStuff is an unrecognised token.  When Stuff is its own class it is still within the same project, so OtherStuff must be available, any ideas?

I have reproduced this with Java 1.7.0_05 + Maven 3.0.4 and, hoping that a move to the latest versions would resolve my issue, Java jdk1.7.0_25 + Maven 3.0.5.  My workaround is to implement Stuff as its own class, but it really should be an inner class.

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE:

I have found that when I remove:

```
import a.b.c.OtherStuff
```

And use a qualified reference in my inner class both Eclipse and Maven are happy:

```
public class ParentStuff {
.
.
.
    public static class Stuff implements a.b.c.OtherStuff<BigInteger>
```

Although, I still think the import should work just fine.

Comment: Importing `OtherStuff` from somewhere?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code you've shown.  you need to give more details.

Comment: The OtherStuff import is the same in both the class and inner class

Comment: Perhaps I should change the title of this post, I am thinking this is a Maven bug, the build is all good in Eclipse, in addition, I now have the class and inner class present in the same project, but the compiler tells me OtherStuff is unrecognised only for the inner class.  If OtherStuff is recognised for the class why not for the inner class?

Comment: Seriously, maven is not broken.

Comment: It is my last resort to suggest there is an issue with any tool, but I have Eclipse and Maven using the same JDK, as a class the import is good, as an inner class it is good for Eclipse but not for Maven, I don't have an explanation for that.

Comment: Note that Eclipse has its own compiler. It does not uses `javac` from the JDK to compile classes, but Maven does. I already had problem with Eclipse compiling fine, whereas `javac` on Maven did not. But it was with complex generics bounded types, back in 2007 (on JDK5). Your situation seems simple, so it should be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an inner class inside your inner class? You may have encountered a compiler bug:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6707323

The fact that moving your import statement from the top of the class fixed the problem is suggestive of this bug.

Comment: Will check on Monday as still have the workaround in place thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I have an inner enum, IIE, inside the inner class, IC.  Following the workaround in the bug you referenced I removed the import for IIE, using a qualification instead, IC.IIE, and now my code compiles. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries! I encountered this problem myself a few days ago and found your question while hunting for the answer. It was driving me nuts... if you can't trust your compiler, who can you trust!?